# What does it mean if $cov(f(x1), f(x2))$ is positive in the context of LHS sampling?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance, sampling, sampling-theory

If cov(f(x1),f(x2)) is positive, does that mean f is close to symmetric along x1 and x2? I am struggling to put this into understandable terms.

Edit:

The context is equation 6 in this paper: http://salserver.org.aalto.fi/vanhat_sivut/Opinnot/Mat-2.4108/pdf-files/emat08.pdf if cov(f(x1), f(x2)) is positive, the sampling error is not reduced by the hypercube sampling technique. I would like to "translate" this to a rule of thumb as to whether lhs sampling will be useful based on the geometry of f.

Comment: positive covariance means as one goes up the other tends to go up and as one goes down the other tends to go down.

Comment: So there's no symmetry implied?

Comment: Do you know anything about $x_1$ and $x_2$?  Are they independent?  How are they distributed?

Comment: @GregoryGrant This is very general, in the context of error from latin hypercube sampling. The context is equation 6 in this paper: http://salserver.org.aalto.fi/vanhat_sivut/Opinnot/Mat-2.4108/pdf-files/emat08.pdf if cov(f(x1), f(x2)) is positive, the sampling error is not reduced by the hypercube sampling technique. I would like to "translate" this to a rule of thumb as to whether lhs sampling will be useful based on the geometry of f.